# Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement (CS0201) (Monty_Hall)

Tags: c#

```
        int Turns;
        int Loses;


        if (ProgramOn == true) {


            if (MontyChoice == 1) {
                goat1 = 2;
                goat2 = 3;
                Console.WriteLine ("1");


                if (PlayerChoice == 1) {
                    Turns == Turns - 1;
                    loses == Loses + 1;

                }
```

I get the error in the title, int Turns and Loses are outside the if ProgramOn loop, do i need to make them public?

Answer (score 5):

I feel like taking risk to answer that but..

```
Turns == Turns - 1;
Loses == Loses + 1;
```

should be

```
Turns = Turns - 1;
Loses = Loses + 1;
```

`==` operator for equality, `=` operator for assignment.

I don't know you have another `loses` as a local variable but be aware `loses` and `Loses` are complete different.

Answer (score 0):

`Turns == Turns - 1;` is not a *statement* (code that "does something") but a *boolean expression* (code that evaluates to true or false). A boolean expression cannot be used like a statement. That's what the error message tells you.

The problem is that you used the comparison operator `==` instead of the assignment operator `=`. Write `Turns = Turns - 1;` or `Turns--;` instead.